# Allow Foreign Key creation without values but enforce not null on update or add

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, nullable

I need to add a foreign key to a table.

The column value will be added by the users eventually over time as each record is modified.

So I  created a FK constraint `with NOCHECK`. But the column can't be left empty, so I declared it as `NOT NULL`. SQL Server won't let me do this on a nullable column, it must have a value or a default.

How can I create a FK that at first will have no entries but should it be modified a Key value must be provided?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do directly in SQL, or you make a field mandatory or not there is no other option. I think you need to look for the solution during creation of the user interface.

Comment: I'm starting to agree with you .  Yet it's a situation that must occur quite often.  You add the new FK column to the table and then the interface that allows you to set it.  it's new so has no value and it's a FK so a value needs to be set.  I would have though the with nocheck would override the is not null constraint.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have an optional relationship - modelling the FK as NULLable while still enforcing the constraint is a common approach here (NULLs FK's will not be checked by the RDBMS). e.g. In the below, we have a `Person` table, but initially during Person capture, we do not know in which City the user lives, so we make the `CityId` foreign key nullable:

```
CREATE TABLE City
(
   CityId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name NVARCHAR(200)
);

CREATE TABLE Person
(
   PersonId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   CityId INT NULL, -- Nullable
   Name NVARCHAR(200),

   CONSTRAINT FK_PersonCity FOREIGN KEY(CityID) REFERENCES City(CityID)
);
```

`Person` will now allow CityID to be NULL (meaning not known), or if non-null, the CityID must be a valid and exist in `City`. The only 'gotcha' here is that you will need to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` Person back to City to consider persons with unknown City.

Another strategy I've seen is to add a DUMMY row into the primary table (e.g. `City(ID = 0, Name = 'Unknown')` and then use this as a default for foreign keys - it will guarantee an `INNER JOIN`.

If you need to enforce the requirement that at a later step that the Foreign Key (City classification) becomes mandatory, I would suggest you do this in your business logic - either in code, or from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a column to an existing table, the new column is created with `NULL` values. So you can't add a `not null` column to a table unless you also specify a default value. In that case, the new field will contain the default value.

If you want to add a new column which will be a mandatory FK, you really only have two options:

- Create the column as nullable, wait until all the fields have been filled, then change the definition of the column to `not null`.
- Create the column as nullable, execute an update filling the fields with the correct value, then change the definition of the column to `not null`.

The advantage of the first option is that you're not holding locks on the table for very long. The disadvantage is that it could take weeks or months to finally getting around to populating every row.

The advantage of the second option is that the field is created and filled very quickly and all of it can be placed in one transaction. The disadvantage is that you are locking the entire table for the duration. It could be very difficult obtaining the lock in the first place and your DBA might have a few choice words about locking it for more than a few seconds.

Get with the aforementioned DBA and decide which way is best for your particular situation.